# Gitignore Ignore all file except for the files inside a subdirectory

Tags: gitignore

I want to add a rule to ignore all apart from the files within a 'Build' folder, but not the folder itself.

I currently have the below which ignores all but the Build folder, but I want only the files within the Build folder, ignoring the folder itself.

```
# Ignore everything in the root except the Build directory.
/*
!.gitignore
!Build/
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter, because git doesn't track folder, only their content.

And if their content is ignored or empty, you won't be able to add their folder, even if that folder is displayed in `git status` as "untracked".

If Build as some content which isn't ignored, you will be to add said content with the shortcut `git add Build`: that doesn't mean `Build/` is "ignored" or "not ignored": it is just a container.